# Microservice Backend project with Jhipster 4.3.0 does not create User tables

Tags: jhipster

Microservice Backend project with Jhipster 4.3.0 does not create User tables (jhi_user, jhi_authotity, jhi_user_authority) only (jhi_persistent_audit-event, jhi_persistent_audit-event_data) are created

````
Here is the result of command: yo jhipster:info  
Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator
##### **JHipster Version(s)**
```
`enter code here`D:\.....\git\dolly-ms-app-consul\dolly-backend
`-- generator-jhipster@4.3.0
### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**
```yaml
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "promptValues": {
      "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
      "nativeLanguage": "fr"
    },
    "jhipsterVersion": "4.3.0",
    "baseName": "dollybackend",
    "packageName": "com.mycompany.myapp",
    "packageFolder": "com/mycompany/myapp",
    "serverPort": "8081",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "hibernateCache": "hazelcast",
    "clusteredHttpSession": false,
    "websocket": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "prodDatabaseType": "mysql",
    "searchEngine": false,
    "messageBroker": false,
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "consul",
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "enableSocialSignIn": false,
    "jwtSecretKey": "aa600103f58d769cb4077acccbf8bdfc276b0eb2",
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "applicationType": "microservice",
    "clientPackageManager": "yarn",
    "testFrameworks": [
      "gatling",
      "cucumber"
    ],
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "skipClient": true,
    "skipUserManagement": true,
    "nativeLanguage": "fr",
    "languages": [
      "fr",
      "en"
    ]
  }
}
```
##### **Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

Client.json
```yaml
{
    "fluentMethods": true,
    "relationships": [],
    "fields": [
        {
            "fieldName": "idClient",
            "fieldType": "BigDecimal",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "numeroCniClient",
            "fieldType": "BigDecimal",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
        {
            "fieldName": "dateNaisClient",
            "fieldType": "LocalDate",
            "fieldValidateRules": [
                "required"
            ]
        },
    ],
    "changelogDate": "20170511190126",
    "javadoc": "Customer entity.\n@author The JHipster team.",
    "entityTableName": "client",
    "dto": "mapstruct",
    "pagination": "pager",
    "service": "serviceImpl"
}

CompteBancaire.json    ```yaml    {…}

Transaction.json   ```yaml   {….}

TypeCompteBancaire.json   ```yaml   {….}

TypeTransaction.json   ```yaml   {….}
```
##### **Browsers and Operating System**
java version "1.8.0_92"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_92-b14)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.92-b14, mixed mode)

git version 2.12.2.windows.2
node: v7.3.0
npm: 3.10.10
bower: 1.8.0
gulp:[09:46:49] CLI version 3.9.1
yarn: 0.23.4
Docker version 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7afaa436
````

Answer (score 1):

With jhipster microservices, your users won't be stored in every microservices. They should be stored in one microservice and referenced loosely by identifier. Notice that your output has

"skipClient": true,
"skipUserManagement": true

This will be a backend microservice and if your microservice needs the user, its identifier can be found in the JWT that gets passed as an authorization header and (I think) gets set in your spring security principal.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt reaction. As i have only one microservice, can i just turn "skipUserManagement" to  false to allow liquibase to create User tables ?

Comment: if you only have one microservice, you shouldn't choose the microservice option and should rather go with monolith. That will give you user management out of the box

Comment: I would like to preserve the microservice architecture because later I would have several microservices. Can i set for example skipUserManagement: false for accout management microservice and skipUserManagement:true for a business microservice?

Comment: Thank you for the link. I've already read this tutorial, but as the presentator doesn't display .yo-rc.json file nor jdl files, my question remains. Can i have for exemple a users-microservice with "skipUserManagement": false; a book-service with skipUserManagement set to true and finally a gateway?

Comment: I just read somewhere that In a JHipster microservice architecture, the User entity is located on the gateway or UAA service.

Comment: It's ok now, i've generated a jhipster 4 project with uaa, a microservice and a gateway. uaa manage user authentification backend. Thank u.